# Cmdlet not recognized

Tags: powershell, module

I wrote my first cmdlet.

.\Scripts\Modules\NewShare\New-Share.psm1

When I add .\Modules to $env:PSModulePath and I import the module, **then I can retrieve the help**, but I am not able to execute it.

> $evn:psmodulepath =
>   C:\Users\bp\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;.\Modules;

When I run the script

```
New-Share -foldername 'C:\MyShare' -sharename 'MyShare'
```

I get the following standard error, as the module doesn't exist.

> The term 'New-Share' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:10
>   + New-Share <<<<  -foldername 'C:\MyShare' -sharename 'MyShare'
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-Share:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

What is the problem?

My powershell module below.

```
function New-Share
{ 
    <#
        .Synopsis
        This function create a new share
        .Description
        This function creates a new share. If the specified folder does not exist, it will be created, and then shared with the specified share name.
        .Example
        New-Share -foldername 'C:\MyShare' -sharename 'MyShare'
        Creates the share with name 'MyShare' for folder 'C:\MyShare'.
        .Parameter foldername
        The folder that needs to be shared. Will be created if it does not exist.
        .Parameter sharename
        The name for the share.
        #Requires PowerShell 2.0
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()] 
     Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True)] 
        [alias("fn")] 
        [string]$foldername, 
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$True)] 
        [alias("sn")]
        [string]$sharename
        ) 

    if (!(test-path $foldername)) 
    { 
        new-item $foldername -type Directory 
    } 

    if (!(get-wmiObject Win32_Share -filter “name='$sharename'”)) 
    { 
        $shares = [WMICLASS]”WIN32_Share”

        if ($shares.Create($foldername, $sharename, 0).ReturnValue -ne 0) 
        {
            throw "Failed to create file share '$sharename'"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you downloaded the module from internet it should be placed in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

1. You should be able to locate it in your session.

   ```
   Get-Module -ListAvailable
   ```
2. Then you can add the module.

   ```
   Import-Module newshare
   ```
3. Verify the cmdlet is available

   ```
   Get-Command -Module newshare
   ```

The error happened because you didn't add the module.

Comment: Note that [it is not recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you install modules to that location.